# Assign var by reference - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables, operators

My question is simple but I have not found anything like my problem. The closest is the singleton pattern but not what I need.

I would do something like this in JavaScript:

```
var a = b = c = 0;
```

Thereby that:

```
c = 3.141516; 
console.log(b); // 3.141516 
console.log(a); // 3.141516 

b = 'Hello World';
console.log(c); // 3.141516 
console.log(a); // Hello World
```

In PHP there is a operator `=&` works just like I want.

Comment: What exactly you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no ["assignment by reference"](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php) in JavaScript. The closest you'll get will look something like this:

```
var a = b = c = {};
c.foo = 3.141516;
console.log(a.foo); // 3.141516
console.log(b.foo); // 3.141516

b.foo = 'Hello World';
console.log(a.foo); // 'Hello World'
console.log(b.foo); // 'Hello World'
```

The variables `a`, `b`, and `c` all reference the same object, so that when you change a property on that object, the 3 references to that object all see the same change.

I assume that the `console.log(c)` line in the example in your question is a copy-paste error, and that you expect it to print `'Hello World'`, not `3.141516`.